# whole screen not scrollable

Tags: flutter, dart

How to make whole screen scrolling instead of just ListView scrollable?

```
return CustomScrollView(
                slivers: [
                  SliverAppBar(
                      actions: [
                       ....
                      ],        
                    ),
                  SliverFillRemaining(
                      child: Column(
                    children: [
                      _showWidget(context, state.tenancy),
                      TabBar(
                        unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black,
                        labelColor: Colors.red,
                        tabs: const [
                          Tab(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.people),
                          ),
                          Tab(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                          )
                        ],
                        controller: _tabController,
                        indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                          child: TabBarView(
                        controller: _tabController,
                        children: [
                          Text("Tab A"),
                         ListView.builder(
                              shrinkWrap: true,                                
                              itemCount: 100,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                return Text("efff");
                              })
                          })),
                        ],
                      )),
                    ],
                  )),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` to your `ListView.Builder`.

Comment: Tried. If I have 100 items in listview, listview not able to scroll up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bottom` parameter  for `TabBar`

```dart
SliverAppBar(
  actions: [
    //  ....
  ],
  bottom: PreferredSize(
    preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(50),
    child: Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: TabBar(
        unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black,
        labelColor: Colors.red,
        tabs: const [
          Tab(
            icon: Icon(Icons.people),
          ),
          Tab(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person),
          )
        ],
        controller: _tabController,
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Now you can just use the column or ListView with `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics` . There might be a better way instead of using `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics`.